# Background color doesn't work after float

Tags: html, css

I'm really new to CSS, so I decided to try to recreate [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) page on my own.

But I came across the following problem:

**HTML**

```
        <!-- Header -->
        <header>
            <h1>w3schools.com</h1>
            <img src="Images/w3schoolslogo.gif">

            <form method="post" action="w3_schools.html">
                <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search w3schools.com"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Search">
            </form>
        </header>
        <!---->

        <!-- Top navigation -->
        <nav class="top_navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Javascript</a></li>
                <li><a href="">JQuery</a></li>
                <li><a href="">XML</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ASP.NET</a></li>
                <li><a href="">PHP</a></li>
                <li><a href="">SQL</a></li>
                <li><a href="">More...</a></li>                   
            </ul>

            <aside>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">References</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Examples</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Forum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </aside>
        </nav>
        <!---->
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;

}

/* Header */
header {
    position: relative;
}

header h1 {
    display: none;
}

header form {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

header form input[type="text"]  {
    border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
}

/* Top navigation */
.top_navigation {
    clear: both;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 80%;
    background-color: green;
}

.top_navigation a:link, .top_navigation a:visited{
    color: #555555;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.top_navigation a:hover {
    color: red;
}

.top_navigation li {
    float: left; 
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.top_navigation aside {
    float:right; 
}
```

The problem is that the background of the nav element is not green. I suppose that it has something with the float, but I have no idea how to fix. I've tried putting `clear:both` almost everywhere, but nothing green was there. :(

Can you please help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've got a typo in the 'clear' property in your .top_navigation class which probably won't help

Comment: Yes, I saw it, but it didn't solve the problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need additional DIV for this. Add `overflow: hidden;` to `.top_navigation`

```
.top_navigation {   
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 70%;
    background-color: green; overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/X4R8K/2/)

Comment: Oh thank you very much! Demo2 seems like the perfect solution!

Answer (score 1):

Your LI elements are floated so the height of the UL bg is 0. So you have a couple options

A CSS 'Clear Fix' is one way to solve this:

CSS:

```
.cf:before, .cf:after {
  content: " "; /* 1 */
  display: table; /* 2 */
}
.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}
.cf {
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
   <ul class="cf">
         <li><a href="">References</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Examples</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Forum</a></li>
         <li><a href="">About</a></li 
   </ul>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8UDVw/1/

Or you can manually set the height of the UL if you know the height of the LI's are not going to change:

```
.top_navigation ul{height:30px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `clear:both` element at the end of the `<nav>`, to make it resize to the floated elements:

```
<nav class="top_navigation">
    <ul>
       ...
    </ul>
    <aside>
       ...
    </aside>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</nav>
```

(this is just an example, of course, don't use inline styles for that)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7gWEu/